# How to make a subquery using RQL (Raven Query Language)?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb4

I have this relationship between DB entities:

```
Entity1
- Name
...

Entity2
- Entity1FK
...
```

What I want to do is to query in RavenDB Studio using RQL all Entity2 which have Entity1 with according name.

This is a RQL query which is not valid but shows what I want to do:

```
from Entity2
where Entity1FK in (
    from Entity1
    where Name = "name"
    select Id
)
```

I want to get all the IDs of Entity1 which have *Name* "name" and use these IDs in the same query. So, how to make the subquery in RQL? Was not able to find this in docs :(

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the **Related Documents** concept:
Look at:

**Create Related Documents**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents

**Load Related Documents**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/load-related-documents

**Query Related Documents**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/query-related-documents

You can access the data of an included document like this in [**RQL**](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql):

```
from "Orders" as o
load o.Company as c
select {
    CompanyName: c.Name
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this using only RQL?